# SignalR comet in production environment is it worth it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, comet, signalr

Is anybody using SignalR in a large scale production environment? If so what is your experience with it and was it worth basing your application around SignalR? Also once you have SignalR incorporated into your application is it pointless to do normal ajax calls?

Comment: SignalR isn't meant to be replacement for vanilla ajax calls. SignalR helps you build real-time, multi-user interactive web applications.

Comment: Here is real-world app built with SignalR: http://jabbr.net/

Comment: @tugberk - How come? I mean if your using SignalR for some portion of your application, why not always use it? Also wouldn't this overcome the problem of urls being in javascript?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **"Also wouldn't this overcome the problem of urls being in javascript"**? This video would be helpful for you to grasp the idea behind SingalR: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/TechDays-2012-Belgium/246

Comment: I meant instead of doing `$.ajax({url: "controller/action"})` you just call a javascript method

Comment: You should watch the video I have posted the link above. SignalR doing slightly the same thing (depending on your browser's capability) and they communicate through URLs as well. So, you cannot hide urls. They are just there. Finally, why do you wanna hang a request open on your server (even if it is async) if you don't need a persistent connection?

Comment: I'll watch the video tonight thanks. I do need a persistent connection for some things, but I was wondering for things where I just need to get data for a combo box or whatever if I should use SignalR

Comment: You can use it though it's a bit of an abuse. But the proxy generation is nice :) I agree and I abuse it all the time. Watch out for long running persistent connections though, if you're hosting can't handle it then don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it here: somebody4u.com/live.

It works a lot better than my long polling code it replaced. The only issue I have with it is I have to run on a single instance in Azure but that's being solved in the next version version (0.5).

I would recommend going live with it is as it's certainly better than anything you (or 99.9999% of people) could implement yourself.